# Times Out when trying to Upload Images to AWS S3 Bucket only when App is Deployed on Fly.io

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, remix.run, fly

I have a Remix full-stack application that uses an S3 bucket to store and retrieve images. When running the application locally, uploading images to S3 from the application works as expected. However, after deploying the application to Fly.io any attempt to upload an image times out, eventually showing a 502 Bad Gateway error and the following text in the fly monitoring terminal: "could not make HTTP request to instance: connection error: timed out". I have tried altering permissions and other settings on the S3 dashboard but nothing seems to help.

This is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my CORS configuration on the S3 bucket:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

The bucket currently has public access enabled (Block all public access off), and Object Ownership is set to "Bucket owner enforced". Any help would be appreciated.

My action has a bunch of other stuff in it as well, but here's the part that calls the upload function:

```
const uploadHandler = unstable_composeUploadHandlers(
    async ({ name, contentType, data, filename }) => {
      if (name !== 'image') {
        return undefined;
      }

      const dataArray1 = [];
      for await (const x of data) {
        dataArray1.push(x);
      }

      const stream = Readable.from(dataArray1);

      const uploadImageService = new UploadImageService(ctx);
      try {
        return await uploadImageService.uploadImage(
          stream,
          folder,
          `${id}-${itemName}.jpg`
        );
      } catch (error) {
        throw serverError({ code: 'image_upload_failed' });
      }
    },
    unstable_createFileUploadHandler()
  );

  let image: FormDataEntryValue | null = null;
  const multipartFormData = await unstable_parseMultipartFormData(request, uploadHandler);
  image = multipartFormData.get('image');
```

This is the service method:

```
async uploadImage(file: Readable, folder?: string, tag?: string): Promise<string> {
    const { s3 } = getS3();

    return await uploadImageToS3(s3, 'BUCKETNAME', file, folder, tag);
  }
```

And this is where it's actually uploaded:

```
export const uploadImageToS3 = async (
  s3: AWS.S3,
  s3Bucket: string,
  buffer: any,
  folder?: string,
  tag?: string
): Promise<string> => {
  const filename = folder ? `${folder}/${tag || uuid()}` : tag || uuid();

  const params = {
    Bucket: s3Bucket,
    Key: filename,
    Body: buffer,
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  };

  try {
    // this is where it times out, it never reaches the console.log() success message below when the app is deployed
    const s3UploadResponse = await s3.upload(params).promise();
    console.log(`File uploaded successfully to ${s3UploadResponse.Location}`);

    return new URL(s3UploadResponse.Location).pathname.substring(1);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error('File upload failed.');
  }
};
```

Comment: So you're uploading the file to S3 from your `action` and *not* directly from the client? Just clarifying. If so, can you show your action and call to upload handler?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I just added a snippet from my action as well as the 2 upload methods (which could obviously be combined).

Answer (score 0):

After being unable to find anything in the code or AWS/Fly settings that would be causing the timeout, I noticed the following message when running the project locally:

> (node:14152) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.
>
> Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
> For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy

So I ran this command on each of my files that used the AWS SDK:

```
npx aws-sdk-js-codemod -t v2-to-v3 example.ts
```

That made some changes to the files and I then needed to install a couple more AWS dependencies, but after that update was all said and done the timeout no longer occurred, so uploading images now works both locally and on the deployment server.